# CakePHP 3 - 1054 Column not found

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have Two tables: cars and car_types. Cars "hasOne" type and Type "hasMany" cars. I've defined this constraints in my models but how can I read the values inside my controller or view without getting the error message like below?

Mysql error message:

> "Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'CarTypes.type_id' in 'on clause'"

I got this error when I do this inside my CarsController:

```
public function index() {
   $query = $this->Cars->find('all', ['contain' => [
        'CarTypes'
   ]]);

   debug($query->toArray());
}
```

**Cars table:**

```
id - type_id - method_id
```

**Car_types table:**

```
id - type
```

**CarTypes model:**

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('car_types');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('Cars', [
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
        ]);
    }
```

**Cars model:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('cars');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasOne('CarTypes', [
            'className' => 'Cars.CarTypes',
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
            'propertyName' => 'type'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: change `Cars.CarTypes` for `CarTypes`,

Comment: That will give the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A record in the parent table (`CarTypes`) may have multiple child records (in `Cars` table), so that relationship is fine as `hasMany`. However, a child record (in the `Cars` table) should **belong** to one `CarType`, not have a `CarType`.

Essentially, `has` is the parent -> child relation, while `belongs` is the child -> parent relation (see [cakephp documentation on associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) for details). So, in the `Cars` change `hasOne` to `belongsTo`:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('cars');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('CarTypes', [
            'className' => 'CarTypes',
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
            'propertyName' => 'type'
        ]);
    }
```

In this case CakePHP will look for the `type_id` field in the `Cars` table, not in the `CarTypes` table.